# Endeca Migration

Tags: endeca, experience-manager, endeca-workbench

I am trying to migrate Endeca 3.1.2 Tools and Framework with Experience manager to 11.0. I have done the steps in the migration guide. However the cartridge templates looks different in 3.1.2 and 11.0. Means the structure of folders and naming. As per migration guide, I have migrated the templates But it is not loading in my experience manager.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs? Did you run `set_templates.sh|bat`? The structure in 3.1.2 is significantly different to that in 11.x.

Comment: @chimbu - Could you explain how your templates now looks and what error you are getting while running set_templates script?